# Deletion of nested attributes does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I seem to be unable to delete items using the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` command but I have done this according to [this tutorial](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised) and the associated [git repo](https://github.com/railscasts/196-nested-model-form-revised/tree/master/questionnaire-after). My models are ...

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :specialties, :inverse_of => :job
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :specialties, allow_destroy: true, :reject_if => :all_blank
end

class Specialty < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :job, :inverse_of => :specialties
end
```

In my `Job` form, I have...

```
<%= f.check_box :_destroy %>
<%= f.label :_destroy, "Remove Specialty" %>
```

When I click the checkbox to delete the a couple of `specialties`, nothing happens. I checked the server output and received:

> Started PATCH "/jobs/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-07-16 16:15:16 -0400
>
> Processing by JobsController#update as HTML
>
> Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"8VxYXujcKXpLEm8+7B43SLU6X3fH00kIOmFK+nvaBKs=", "job"=>{"name"=>"Cook", "description"=>"Makes the food.", "specialties_attributes"=>{"2"=>{"name"=>"", "description"=>"", "_destroy"=>"1", "id"=>"3"}, "3"=>{"name"=>"", "description"=>"", "_destroy"=>"1", "id"=>"4"}}}, "commit"=>"Update Job", "id"=>"1"}
>
> Job Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "jobs".* FROM "jobs" WHERE "jobs"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "1"]]
>
> **Unpermitted parameters: _destroy**
>
> **Unpermitted parameters: _destroy**
>
> **Unpermitted parameters: _destroy**
>
> **Unpermitted parameters: _destroy**

What did I miss? I've gone through the tutorial and repo a bunch of times and I can't see where I've gone off.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That's because of [strong_parameters](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html). You now have to `permit` keys. In your action:

`params.permit(:_destroy)`

Comment: AHHH!!! I tried this! ... But I did it on `Job`, not `Specialties`. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Simple mistakes can be hardest to catch!

Comment: @Jeff Where *exactly* did you put the params.permit(:_destroy)? I'm baffled!

Comment: In side job_controller.rb >  def job_params params.require(:job).permit(:id, :description, :specialty_fields_attributes => [:id, :job_id, :avatar, :_destroy])
end

Answer (score 12):

I like @Damien Roche's answer but its just for not confusion to any one. follow this

```
In job_controller.rb

private
 def job_params 
   params.require(:job).permit(:id, :description, :specialty_fields_attributes => [:id, :job_id, :avatar, :_destroy])
 end
```

Comment: Thanks, I definitely wasn't thinking to put `:_destroy` into my sub-attributes array!