# Rails 4 deleting nested attributes, works on create but not on edit/update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-attributes

So I'm working from this [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1).

And I'm aware that there have been some changes in Rails 4 for Strong parameters.

[First relevant question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20117959/accepts-nested-attributes-for-rails-4-is-not-deleting).

[Second relevant question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17686440/deletion-of-nested-attributes-does-not-work)

I've quadruple checked my implementation, but can't see where I'm going wrong.  As it is at the moment, ticking the "destroy" box when submitting the patient initially (i.e. the create method) works as intended, and will delete any medication that has a checked box and permitting any that does not (from the three form inputs it provides).

However when I subsequently edit that patient, any medications that **don't** get checked to be deleted are duplicated (so I end up with more attached medications than I started with), and any that are checked for deletion don't seem to change.

So if there two medicines attached "Med1" and "Med2", and I edit the patient, if both are marked for deletion I will still end up with "Med1" and "Med2".  If only "Med1" is marked for deletion I will end up with "Med1" and "Med2" and an extra "Med2".  If neither are marked for deletion I will end up with two each of "Med1" and "Med2".

```
#patient.rb
class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :procedures
has_many :medications, dependent: :destroy
has_many :previous_operations, dependent: :destroy

accepts_nested_attributes_for :medications, :allow_destroy => true, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:name].blank? },
end
```

---

```
#views/patients/_form.html.erb
<%= form_for(@patient) do |f| %>
  <% if @patient.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@patient.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this patient from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @patient.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.fields_for :medications do |builder| %>
    <%= render "medication_fields", :f => builder %>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :first_name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :first_name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :last_name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :last_name %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

---

```
#views/patients/medications_fields.html
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :name %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :_destroy, "Remove Medication" %>
  <%= f.check_box :_destroy %>
</div>
```

---

```
#controllers/patients_controller.rb
class PatientsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_patient, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /patients
  # GET /patients.json
  def index
    @patients = Patient.all
  end

  # GET /patients/1
  # GET /patients/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /patients/new
  def new
    @patient = Patient.new
    3.times { @patient.medications.build }
  end

  # GET /patients/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /patients
  # POST /patients.json
  def create
    @patient = Patient.new(patient_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @patient.save
        format.html { redirect_to @patient, notice: 'Patient was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @patient }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @patient.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /patients/1
  # PATCH/PUT /patients/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @patient.update(patient_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @patient, notice: 'Patient was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @patient.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /patients/1
  # DELETE /patients/1.json
  def destroy
    @patient.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to patients_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
    flash[:notice] = "Patient was successfully deleted."
  end

  private

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def patient_params
      params.require(:patient).permit(:first_name, :last_name, medications_attributes: [:name, :_destroy])
    end

end
```

I've been super careful and checked over a million times the :_destroy flag being allowed through strong parameters, but still no dice.

Any help appreciated, must be something obvious that I just can't see.

**EDIT**

Changing this...

```
    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def patient_params
      params.require(:patient).permit(:first_name, :last_name, medications_attributes: [:name, :_destroy])
    end
```

To this...

```
    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def patient_params
      params.require(:patient).permit!
    end
```

appears to work correctly, so I'm still sure it's something to do with strong parameters, but the latter is less secure I'm sure and not best practice.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

when you are doing

```
# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def patient_params
  params.require(:patient).permit!
end
```

*it permits all of your attributes and it's not recommended*. It's more of a hack rather than a solution.

If you look at your question

`Rails 4 deleting nested attributes, works on create but not on edit/update`

and if you look at your params permitted

```
# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def patient_params
  params.require(:patient).permit(:first_name, :last_name, medications_attributes: [:name, :_destroy])
end
```

*This will work on creating patients but **not on updating or editing them*** because when you create a *new record it **doesn't require you to permit id*** but *when you want to update or edit a record **you need its id*** to be permitted as well.

Fix:

Just *pass the **id** attribute to permitted attributes* and it will work for you

```
# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def patient_params
  params.require(:patient).permit(:id, :first_name, :last_name, medications_attributes: [:id,:name, :_destroy])
end
```

Comment: Note to anyone else reading this that I had to permit the medication_attribute :id, not the patient attribute.    params.require(:patient).permit(:first_name, :last_name, medications_attributes: [**:id,** :name, :_destroy])

Comment: @user2792268 updated my answer. You should permit patients id as well else it will give you trouble while updating patients

Comment: Is there a reason :id is not included by default in the params.permit when generating objects with rails generate scaffold model field_a field_b:date field_c:integer field_d etc.?

Comment: @user2792268 don't know but it should as clearly It's required in updating a record

Comment: If :id is included by default then permit list could not be reused for create.

Comment: @GeorgeShaw No, same method can be used for both create and update actions

Comment: @mandeep If you supply :id to create it will update that record rather than create a new one. That creates a security hole that strong parameters are specifically intended to prevent.

Comment: @mandeep In update I generally use:id param and do the find, then if found, I use the same permit list as create (no :id) to do the update. :id is filtered out for both as it has already been consumed and is no longer need in update.

Comment: @GeorgeShaw Are you saying that the solution in the answer is not secure? If so, please explain more details for your solution. I want to apply it.

Comment: @Mandeep I had very similar problem and adding just medication id solved it. I think you don't need to patient id.

Comment: @Wit Only allow the param :id (wherever in the params) to be supplied on Update, never on Create. If supplied on Create, then that specific record will be Updated rather than a new one created. This falls out naturally in the code so only one strong-params statement is needed if the ids are consumed by upate to locate the records of interest first before passing the filtered params in where id is no longer needed.

Comment: @GeorgeShaw So you suggest we have 2 methods by replacing `def patient_params` with `def create_patient_params` and `def update_patient_params` where the only difference is that `update_patient_params` has `:id` in its `medications_attributes`?

Comment: @Wit (old but maybe still relevant to answer...) No, update should remove the :id parameter before passing the remaining parameters to a single, shared, strong params statement. If someone were to call Create with an :id parameter, the system will update that record rather than create a new one. You must ensure there is no :id parameter or any user allowed to access Create could potentially modify any arbitrary record.